# python mechanize new page

Tags: python, mechanize

I am using python and mechanize to login into a site. I can get it to login, but once I am in I need to have mechanize select a new form and then submit again. I will need to do this 3 or for times to get to the page I need. Once I am logged in how od I slect the form on the 2nd apge?

```
import mechanize
import urlparse

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("https://test.com")
print(br.title())
br.select_form(name="Login")
br['login_name'] = "test"
br['pwd'] = "test"
br.submit()

new_br = mechanize.Browser()
new_br.open("test2.com")
new_br.select_form(name="frm_page2")  # where the error happens
```

I get the following error.

```
FormNotFoundError: no form matching name 'frm_page2'
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you sure the form you are selecting is in the code you are looking at?

Comment: yes. I have checked several times, on page 2 it is there. It is like I go back to the login screen when I try the above. If print(br.title()) it is the original login screen

Comment: And are you sure the login process went well ?

Comment: yes if I run it by itself I can get to the 2nd page

Comment: You will to provide more information here. Can you check that the return html contains the good page, or an error message saying "Sorry, wrong password or username". Can you please paste some input ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `name=' '` when finding a form because Mechanize already uses 'name' itself.

If you want to find something by name, you need to do:

```
br.select_form(attrs={'name': 'Login'})
```